# How to plot a graph with CAShapeLayer?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-animation, cashapelayer

Is it possible to draw just a curve with a given line width using CAShapeLayer? It seems it can only draw filled shapes. I want to draw an animated plot graph. Just a line, not a shape.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it seems you can in fact draw lines with CAShapeLayers. Try something like this:

```
UIBezierPath *graphPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[graphPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(x, y)];
[graphPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x, y + h)];
[graphPath closePath];
```

Then put it in a CAShapeLayer:

```
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
[shapeLayer setFrame: aFrame];
[shapeLayer setPath: [graphPath CGPath]];
[shapeLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[shapeLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

You can change `graphPath` to plot any curve/line you want to graph.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Upvoted! To get only the line, I had to set fillColor to nil.